# Cardinality of a power set? Or is "all subsets of a set" $\neq$ power set?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Again as usual, group theory is muddling me up.
A proof of the Sylow $I$ theorem starts as follows

> Let $X$ be the set of all subsets of $G$ with $|A|=p^m$.

where, the setting I have for Sylow $I$ is

> Let $G$ be a group $|G|=n$ where $p$ is a prime that divides $n$. Then we can write $n=p^mr$ where $p$ does not divide $r$....(and the theorem is stated).

The issue is in the above notation, shouldn't $|A|=2^n$? The set of **all** subsets of $G$ that has cardinality $n$ is the power set, right? Then isn't its cardinality $2^n$? Why is it $p^m$? We can't just pick and choose that for convenience when we're discussing the power set.

Can someone explain why??

Comment: They are defining $X$ to be the set of all of those subsets of $G$ which happen to have order a power of $p$.

Comment: So it's *not* the power set? Is this more of like the English I'm confused with ....

Comment: It is definitely not the power set!  It's a subset of the power set.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tags fit the question itself. But I'm not sure what tags should be here as well.

Comment: The first one should start "Let $X$ be the set of all subsets$~A$..." as otherwise the condition makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the English. The statement is defining $X$ as the set of all subsets $A$ of $G$ *such that* the cardinality of $A$ is $p^m$. Namely,
$$X=\{A\subseteq G : |A|=p^m\}.$$

Here $A$ is a free variable, not the power set of $G$.

Comment: +1: It would be better if they'd said "...all subsets $A$ of $G$ such that..." instead.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Ha! I wasn't actually thinking about *your* phrasing, but I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @CameronBuie. Yes indeed. Suppose I wrote "The set of all subsets of G such that the Riemann hypothesis is true."